Is it reasonable for a PhD student to take a weekday off after having to work on a weekend?
I'm having to come into the lab on weekends to get the fast-growing organisms I work with at the right stage of development for my experiments, I cannot predict the dates or times for that precisely (unless ~20 hours prior) because the time they take to get there depends on the mutations I never worked with before and their response to tiny fluctuations in temperature. Today (Saturday) I came in for ~6 hours and will have to come in tomorrow for a few hours. I found a day next week when I don't have to come in. My PI hates not seeing me in the office 9-5 every single weekday with no exceptions even at lunch time and even if I had to work late the day before or work weekends for the reasons described above. Is it still reasonable to tell my PI that I'm taking a day off because I had to work during the weekend? I ask because I expect them to get livid as usual. Can I complain to someone if they react like this over me trying to take control of my own work schedule?
I heard a suggestion earlier to change advisors - I can't find anyone else who works in this field at my institution and my research council funding can't be transferred elsewhere. I'm two months away from finishing my second year (out of 4 years of funding) so I'd hate to start my project again somewhere else.
Edit to make question more to the point and add: I'm not complaining about working weekends, I love working weekends. I did pull all-nighters before and I did work in the lab three weeks in a row before including weekends. I was happy with all of that but not happy with angry emails from my PI asking why I'm not at my desk at a certain time and why I left the office without their permission. It doesn't seem to matter how many days in a row I work or whenever I had to work at night, I feel I'm still not "allowed" to take time off. I don't know how to tell my PI that I shouldn't need their permission for this, but I feel they won't take it well.

‘My PI hates not seeing me in the office 9-5 every single weekday with no exceptions …’ How do you know this? And what does ‘livid’ look like in your situation?

@Aruralreader they told me I'm supposed to sit at my desk 9-5 and ask their permission before leaving the office, e.g. for lunch. I try to argue but all I get is "yes but I can't talk to you if you're not in the office", I argued that we have email/Slack for that, they say it's not the same as talking in person. We had several conversations like this, with no resolution. By "livid" I mean telling me exactly the same things as before but as a loud and long rant, waving their hands around and cussing a lot (not at me though). This happens without warning but generally not triggered by me.

Well, at least he or she is making his or her expectations clear, so there’s that. Are you the first person in the lab to have to tend to wet- and dry-lab responsibilities? If not, how did those others handle their workloads?

@Aruralreader I'm the first person in my lab who's interested in a particular developmental stage and does these experiments with this timing, previous students whom I've met rarely had to come in during the weekend or work late.

How much uncertainty is there in your growth patterns? Can you time the start of the growth in such a way that it won't fall on the weekends? Having worked experimentally, I know that it may be difficult, but maybe, with experience, you can at least partially control it.

If there's no potential supervisors in your exact field at your institution is there anyone in a closely related field? Or even someone with a close enough field that their lab is suitable for your wet work? Theoretically you could move to a different lab in your institution and have an internal supervisor and an external one from another institution, although this might be hard to get someone to agree to if you don't have a preexisting relationship.

Turn the question around to make the PI rationalise his lividity. Calmly and politely ask: 'I can see this request is causing a problem for you. Can you please clarify what is the difficulty it presents for you?' Only then can you start to address the underlying problems

Yes, it's reasonable.
However, that doesn't mean your PI must be reasonable.

It is reasonable in a salaried job where you are paid per hour. It is less reasonable if you want to obtain an academic degree that will later earn you a management position with a pay grade outside of collectively agreed employment relationships.

@PeterKämpf It is also reasonable to occasionally take days off if you want an academic degree or get a management position at some point in your career.

@PeterKämpf For most people a PhD "earns" them another poorly compensated position called a post doc and then because there are simply too many applicants for the few academic jobs there are they end up in industry trying to figure out how to sell their time as an academic for a job that pays much less than someone of their capabilities would likely make having spent their time getting 10 years of industry experience instead. I don't know what world you are in where a PhD is an easy ticket to a high pay management gig.

@PeterKämpf If you can't suceed in your PhD without working 24/7, then you are going to make a bad manager.

@PeterKämpf Salary means not "paid per hour."

@PeterKämpf an academic degree that will later earn you a management position with a pay grade outside of collectively agreed employment relationships A PhD in industry, in average, means nothing to not much. Sure there are places where it counts because f the position, but this a tiny minority. A PhD gives zero advantage when it comes to management - I would even say that this is a hinderance because you come to the position with no management experience at all.

@WoJ Well, you learn something about working with and for unreasonable people, evidently. Which has utility, that's how customers are

I think there is, as always, a difference between Europe and the US here. It seems that in Europe a PhD means a lot more than in the US. Which makes sense as it also seems to be harder to obtain...

@AzorAhai-him- - Depends on the country. I'm salaried but my contract is for 37.5 hours a week. If I do more than that I expect to be compensated for it in the same way that the business doesn't expect me to do less.

Your advisor does not sound reasonable and it might be that you have no choice but to either meet their demands or leave. If they are prone to raising their voice and swearing, it does not sound like a good situation to stay in. That said, it also doesn’t sound as though you are doing everything you could at your end to manage the situation, so it might be worth trying better communication first.
Instead of working 6 hours on Saturday without notice and then telling your advisor that you will take a weekday off, try approaching them on the Friday, telling that that it looks as though you will need to work on Saturday, and asking if it is okay to do that and then take a day off during the week. They might still say “no” because they might really be unreasonable and want you there all the time. Or they might say “yes” because maybe the real issue is communication (i.e. they need to know when they can expect you to be there and when not to have confidence that you are working professionally or to feel that they are in control of their lab) or respect (insecure advisors might need more show of respect that those who are more secure in their position).
You’ve said that they want you to be at your desk all the time, even during lunch — but later said in the comments that they have said they want you to ask permission before leaving for lunch. Again, this might be more about communication and respect from their perspective than about wanting you to work through lunch. Does it really cost you anything to stop by their office on your way to lunch and ask/tell them (e.g., “I’m just off for lunch now if that’s okay?”)? [Also check that your expectations regarding the duration of a lunch-break match, as that could be another hidden issue if the two of you aren’t communicating well].

To add an example to that last point: in my country, a half hour lunch break is normal (and just eating at your desk while working is common), but I’ve worked with students from countries where a 2-hour lunch break is normal. Because I didn’t know that 2 hours was normal where they were from and they didn’t know that 30 minutes is standard here, and we hadn’t discussed it, I was shocked when the first of these students went missing for 2 hours in the middle of every day in their first week. I didn’t immediately say anything, so it gave me the false impression they were lazy and unreliable.

This. It’s always better to tell and plan in advance (both your work and off-days) rather than report once it’s done, or worse, explain and demand afterwards.
Also, it’s usually best to ask "When (or how) can I take my days off?" rather than "Can I take my days off?".

@Significance Why not include that anecdote in the answer itself?

@AzorAhai-him- I don’t like to change an answer too substantially after it has received a lot of upvotes— what if the existing upvoters don’t like the revision?

That's fair, but I would hate to see that info lost - I didn't know that there were cultures with 2 h lunch breaks.

@AzorAhai-him- it's not only (country) culture. In my place (within the same country) I worked in a place where 1 hour lunch is common, and then at another place where 2 hour lunch is common. It also depends on the company culture.

@AzorAhai-him- Lunch breaks of 2 or even 3 hours are common in Mediterranean countries (e.g., France, Spain, Greece) and in China and Brazil. People in these countries usually take a long lunch break, but then go back to work until 7 or 8pm.

A great place for all this comparative anthropology is definitely in the comments

There are several ways to think about this. You say you are at a UK university. In which case there are almost certainly rules around how much leave you can taken and time off in lieu etc. Now in generally, these are almost certainly observed more in the breach, than in the observance. But its something to bare in mind because....
Your supervisor can huff and shout and be unpleasant all they like, but they can't get rid of you. No UK supervisor has the power to do that. Instead they would either have to start a disciplinary procedure against you, or a failure-to-progress process. If what you are doing is within the rules, and your project is going well, then they are not going to get very far with either of these.
Of course, just because they can't get rid of you, doesn't mean they can't make your life difficult. They can not fund your experiments, or they could not proof read your work, or support your development, help you meet your community, or they could write you a poor reference. Some of these things would be them stepping outside the rules they are supposed to follow (not funding sufficient experiments that you could get a PhD, proof reading your work), others less so (getting you networking opportunities, writing you a reference).
You could of course go down the formal route. If they routinely shout during work hours I would be tempted to lodge a formal complaint about them. My university has two systems - one is a formal complain procedure, via the departmental PGR lead, or via HR, the other is something called "report and support", which is an anonymous system where people can report worries they have about members of staff.
Its worth bearing in mind that a PhD is not a 9-5 job. I always say to people that work with me that I don't expect them to routinely work more than 40 hours a week, but there will be times when that is necessary because of the nature of the project. My personal feeling is that people should take time off because they need time off, not on some close accounting of how many hours they've worked in a given week. I think if you need time off to do something particular, OR need time off because your are in need of a break, then that's fine, and it will balance out with the extra time people work, rather than saying "you worked 2.5 hrs extra on Saturday so you should get 2.5hrs off in the week". But everyone runs their group differently.
However, the BBSRC does specify that students get 8 weeks off a year, and your supervisor should make that possible for you. If they are not its probably worth saying to them "When do I get the time off my studentship specifies", and if they say "you don't", then, again, it might be worth speaking to someone more superior.

This answer is actually relevant to the UK context. The only thing I would add is that as well as making a formal complaint you might have some kind of other support system available depending on your institution - e.g. PGR reps or an assigned pastoral point of contact. You could also talk to your UCU rep if you're a member.

After working 12 days straight (2 weeks and the weekend in between, they probably would be overdue for a break.  So they may as well take it after 7 days when they've got a good chance,  and will probably be more useful for doing so

I'm in the UK, but not in life sciences.
Your taking time off after working through the weekend is far more normal than a PI getting visibly angry at you for doing so, or expecting students to be chained to their desks.
In some circumstances a quiet word along the lines of "try to push through until you've got these results, then take a break" is sensible, especially if you'd been taking it easy before the recent round of experiments.
Most academics that I know would be in favour of their students getting some fresh air at lunchtime.
Do check your department's/university's guidance on PhD workload, but also their rules on safe lone working.  We have pretty strict rules on when and how people are allowed to work in the lab outside normal hours, and what they're allowed to do.  It's quite likely your PI is in breach of those too (even if you've got 24 hour access - that just means you're trusted to work within those rules)

I think you need to set aside your academic hat for one moment and treat this as a simple workplace-employment issue.
Academics often have little training as managers, while students have little experience of what is normal and acceptable for a work setting, so there can occasionally be errors in complying with statutory employment laws. However this looks like a mild communication issue. Evidently this is stressful for you, but you’re a joint owner of this partnership and your duty here is to communicate maturely and amicably with your PI and assertively set appropriate expectations, so that the PI can see how you are fulfilling your hours, just as an employee might with their manager.
In a workplace setting a simple way to do this could be at a weekly progress meeting or in a progress report. Before going in at the weekend, you explain why you might need to go in, and if so, that you intend to be off on whichever day it is. This is demonstrating initiative and self-management skills. Your work-hours are visible to your PI, and if there’s any essential tasks to be done in the laboratory on the absent day then these can be reassigned in an orderly way. This would be demonstrating responsible communication and teamwork which lets everyone know what is going on, and is certainly not skiving!
If that is still not satisfactory, then sit down and agree a more formal written list of objectives or ‘job description’ of tasks you and your PI agree are appropriate, so your focus is on results and not hours. Job descriptions are for everyone, not just salaried staff. Also, ask politely why it is necessary to be in the lab? Is there some tangible reason to be constantly available? (or is that simply your PI’s insecurity.)
And, try to develop a regular habit of engaging in personal smalltalk (without over-sharing!). This helps illustrates your life is far richer than just a scientific experiment, and establishes a familiar context within which you may routinely prioritise relationships and personal tasks at appropriate times during your day - which is a normal thing to do. Smalltalk develops trust for when you need to tackle more difficult conversations in the future.
It’s worth remembering that your PhD will bear no more correlation with the hours you spend, than it does to the word-count in your thesis! Its the quality of time that matters.

Certainly.
If you need to, tell your supervisor "I'm really exhausted and feeling unwell today, I won't come in" and be done with it.
I had a hard nosed supervisor in the pre covid times and certainly wasn't expected in the office 9-5. A PhD is a research project not a job. Your relationship sounds unhealthy. Ensure you have a papertrail and get the student wellfare people or supervisor relations or what ever that section is called in your university involved (There will be one, ask around). If you're having this stress in your second year you're not going to succeed until the end.
Also talk to other students under this PI how they handle it.

Actually, in some places, getting a doctorate does involve having a "job" with the university or the lab. I know it happens in UK, but don't know if it is the universal practice there. And "telling" your supervisor seems like a risky practice.

And this advice, the first sentence, can get you fired, so it would be dangerous to act upon. That would be truly "done" with it.

yes, many PhDs had a side gig at the uni teaching / assisting. I had one too (in the UK). Those are "paid" by the hour. But why is calling in sick a risky strategy. Surely if the PI cares about attendance then letting them know in advance you're not coming will assuade them. What are they going to say, "I don't care, get your your sick ass in the office?"

Actually it sounds like a lie. The OP hasn't suggested such things. Again, OP, take such advice at your own risk. Given what you say about the supervisor, I wouldn't expect understanding.

@Buffy "firing" a PhD student in the UK is almost impossible. Hell, "firing" a employee is almost impossible. In my university the process for firing an underperforming member of staff takes a minimum of 6 months.

@Buffy In the UK, supervisors do not have the power to "fire" people.

@Kalliope, do they have the power to remove them from the lab that they supervise, and perhaps, fund? Or is the supervisor just stuck with them if they judge them uncooperative or underperforming? I don't charge the OP with that FWIW. But some of this seems to imply that a student has some superpower to control a supervisor and/or their lab.

@Buffy Neither of these, in my experience. Please be conscious that the world does not resolve around the US. Many (most) PhDs in the UK are funded by the university itself; that's how you avoid many form of abuse. "But some of this seems to imply that a student has some superpower to control a supervisor and/or their lab" I argue the complete opposite. The student has signed a contract with the university where none of what is described is stated. What you in fact do, is giving supposed power to the supervisor, and be angry when these are questioned.

Kalliope is correct, most PhDs are not funded by supervisors. I changed supervisors part way through my PhD because my main supervisor left. This had no effect on my funding because my funding is from my university. If I fell out badly with my supervisors I could change supervisors. Unfortunately it sounds like the OP may not be able to change supervisors because there's nobody else in their field at their institution.

Good point from Bryan Krause. A couple of others though. You've nearly completed your second year, so by now you're - to some degree - expected to manage your time. And while I would have instinctively replied,yes of course have a day off if you've done more than a week without (for the sake of your health at least), and as you say, research can't always be timetabled. At some point you'll probably be pulling all-nighters; it would be a shame to lose results because you weren't there. But, conversely, you need rest and time away to be able to maintain your optimum, so it's a tricky balance.
Unfortunately these are things you'll have to deal with eventually, whether this PI is at fault or not.

"My PI hates not seeing me in the office 9-5 every single weekday with no exceptions even at lunch time and even if I had to work late the day before or work weekends for the reasons described above."
If you receive the current UKRI stipend, this would be illegal as it falls below minimum wage. It doesn't matter whether you're an employee or not - in the UK, it's illegal to have someone work below the national minimum wage, even without a contract. The academic conventional wisdom widely shared on this Stack doesn't override labor laws and workers' rights. I suggest contacting your union, as should many academics and especially people on this Stack.

The stipend specifically isn't a wage though.

Unfortunately there is an exception in the minimum wage legislation that specifically excludes students undertaking work required for a degree program.

And anyway, even if it were not specifically excluded, someone working 40 hours a week at minimum wage takes home £18,726 a year. This yeats BBSRC stipend is £19,237 outside of London. Let's not complicate an already tense situation.

I'm finding it hard to be sympathetic, actually, since you describe these as "your" experiments. You are, in effect, working for yourself, toward your future career. What happens to your cultures if you take time off during the week and something bad happens to them?
Many of us in grad school worked through the week-ends, though we did so in our own space, perhaps, not in a lab. Many academic professionals take little time "off" from duties, whether teaching or research. Even week-ends can be when you catch up.
Sorry.
Yes, you can ask for time off, but it seems unlikely that it will be granted, given what you say about the supervisor. And, if they are the source of your income, it seems overly risky to press too hard. Being fired as uncooperative is just about the worst case outcome.

I got the impression that you misread my question and thought I hate working weekends which is wrong - I love working weekends, at least because the lab is quiet and all the equipment is available. I just wish I had the flexibility with my lab hours that every other PhD student seems to have. The problem is, I have to wrestle with my PI to make this "my" project and be less like a technician. The organism (sorry it's a bit of a niche one and I try to keep myself unidentifiable) is fine on every other day I just need to collect it after a few days after it hatches. I hope this makes more sense.

No, I make no such assumption. Presumably you are paid for your weekday work. You say "having to work on a weekend". But that is your choice, given the requirements of your research.

Yes thank you, but if I didn't work weekends then I wouldn't be able to complete these experiments so I don't understand what I'm meant to do about that but that's ok. May I ask a nagging question - is it possible to finish my PhD if my supervisor and I continue squabbling about working hours for another two years? I don't know how common that is. Thank you!

I don't know your supervisor, but fighting with them over anything is not the best strategy to finish. Or to move on.

This is terrible advice. Burn out is real and one needs to take breaks. Also it is clear from the Q that the cultures don't need 24/7 supervision, just occasionally on the weekend.

@ic_fl2, if it is only "occasionally" on the week end, why is it worth another day off? And, are you suggesting that if the OP is paid for 40 hours a week that they only need to "work" 32 because they have their "own experiments" to manage on a week end? How many employers will agree?

@Buffy If you're paid 40 hours a week, work 8 on the weekend and 32 in the week that is completely fine. But as stated elsewhere a PhD is not a job but a long slog. And if you need a day off after working the weekend you should take one. I certainly want to see my staff fresh in the office able to think and do good work, not be coffee drinking zombies.

Do you think their "own experiments" are things they are doing entirely for themself, and not part of the accepted work of the lab, but ones they are responsible for? I guess that's possible, but I think everyone else is assuming the latter is the case.

@JonathanZ, no, I don't think that, but I do think that it is their own choices that make it necessary. The lab has other work, I'd guess, that requires coverage; possibly 24/7. I also think it is reasonable to ask, but not to "tell", the supervisor.

It's in the very beginning of their question: it's the fast growing organism's choice. And a 24/7 coverage requirement is incredibly unlikely, considering the PI's expressed desire for the OP being at their desk 8/5.

I’ve worked plenty of weekends and late nights in my academic career, and had plenty of friends in different fields who’ve done the same and more — but I’ve never known an academic workplace that also required strict 9–5 attendance on weekdays.  That’s always seemed like a generally-understood bargain; and here the supervisor seems to be reneging on their half of that bargain.  And obviously “fighting with” a supervisor is never good, but accepting unlimited demands from the supervisor isn’t good either — sometimes standing up to it is the right call.

I’ve certainly worked in groups where I was still required to be in the office 9-5 despite working all weekend or late into the night. I’d say it’s fairly common in academia — but that does not make it reasonable and is something we should aim to move away from.

@Buffy: In the UK, PhD students are not normally employees. They are supported through a stipend. There are no contracted hours.
